# Switch to Firefox browser using Selenium

Tags: macos, selenium

Firefox browser only launches on Dock on my Mac but active screen shown is still Eclipse.

How can the focus be shifted to Browser?

```
public class FirefoxFirst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/varunnadimpalli/Downloads/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
```

selenium :3.3.1
Mac:`10.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Strange why it wouldn't swap focus to firefox, if it is not in focus but still open try

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

If it is minimized you can try going through the windows handles

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

See if that is able to bring the firefox window up.

Comment: Hi..it does not bring up the firefox window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this works. Try maximizing the browser,

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Also, don't forget to add implicit wait after initiating the browser.

Note - I don't have enough points to comment this. else i have commented instead of writing this as answer.